# Is it right to say "Every ten hours", "Once in ten hours", or "Once in every ten hours"?

Tags: time

It’s a website where a listing is updated only once in a hundred hours. But when a user activates paid features, his listing can be updated ten times faster meaning once in ten hours.

Which is the correct version to state such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is “…can be updated once every 10 hours.” 
The preposition “in” isn’t necessary if you use “every”. You can use in if you want to add a noun, such as “period”:  …can be updated once **in** every 10 hour period.

**Using “in”**
“Once in 10 hours”  Example sentence:
He was supposed to call me every hour. But he was lazy. He called me once in 10 hours!
“in 10 hours”  Example sentences: 
I will be finished in 10 hours. 
He left Boston and arrived in Pittsburgh in 10 hours.